# Inserted Data not visible outside the application server where has been created over a remote call to a second application

Tags: postgresql, oracle, transactions, isolation-level, propagation

I encountered a problem when using postgreSQL 11 and Jboss EAP 7.3 : I have two separate applications deployed on Jboss EAP 7.3 in two different node .

The 1st application has created some data and has made a call to the 2nd application via a remote call .
When fetching data in the 2d application nothing is found knowing that everything is in the same transaction even the call to the 2nd application's ejb was done using Required transaction propagation .

This case is working fine when using Oracle Database and not in PostegreSQL.

The Default_isolation_level is READ_Commited for both Oracle and PosteGreSQL .

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Without the the code you are using to do the calls this is unanswerable. Add said code to your question.

Comment: The problem is not in the code ,im asking if there is any issue with transaction propagation ,any limitaion in jboss eap with postgresql does the global transaction supported ?

Comment: "nothing is found knowing that everything is in the same transaction even the call to the 2nd application's ejb was done using Required transaction propagation" what does that mean?

Comment: Does postgres support "transaction propagation"?

Comment: @bobflux the remotecall and the process are running in a single transaction handled by the transaction coordinator .

Comment: If the process and the remotecall use two different postgresql connections then they will be in two different transactions so they won't see each other's updates until they're commited... unless it uses [set transaction snapshot](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-SNAPSHOT-SYNCHRONIZATION) but that is not compatible with read commited isolation level you use.

Comment: [Note that each transaction is still fully autonomous; the various sessions are not “inside” the same transaction. They can’t see each other’s work, and if two different clients modify the database, those modifications are not visible to any other session, including the ones that are sharing the snapshot. You can think of the snapshot as the “base” view of the database, but each session can modify it (subject, of course, to the usual rules involved in modifying the same tuples, or getting serialization failures).](https://thebuild.com/blog/2019/02/11/whats-up-with-set-transaction-snapshot/)

Comment: So the real question would be: if postgres does not support the feature you're using, why doesn't your database library raise an error when you try to use it?

Comment: @bobflux Yes ,they use different connections , Jboss is handling the connection creation via a declared datasource.This configuration is working fine when using oracle , so i think that postgresql is handling transaction differently  or by session ?

Comment: I guess oracle supports sharing one transaction across several client connection, but postgres doesn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have some trivial error, like you connect to different databases, the explanation must be that the first application didn't commit its database transaction before the second application tries to read the data.

Before a transaction is committed, all its effects are invisible outside the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your response , The process is running in a single XA transaction , handled by the transaction coordination .

Comment: That won't help you. These are still different transactions when seen from the database side.

Comment: is it due to the different sessions  ?

Comment: Each session has its own transaction. The distributed transaction is not really a database transaction, it is a separate construct that uses the two-phase commit protocol to commit the individual transaction. The question that begs to be asked at this point is: why are you using a distributed transaction for operations on a single database?

Comment: Operations are done by different applications deployed in separate servers so that is why we are using a distributed transactions .

Comment: Anyway, you have your explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much !